python add a hotkey but stop the keypresses from passing through to other apps
Let's say I want a python program to bind to Shift+f. If you open up notepad and in there press Shift+f, then a capital F will appear. This means notepad received the keypresses. If you instead press win+f, for example, then an 'f' will not appear, because windows binded it to do something else.
I want my python program to do the same thing. When the user presses shift+f, only my program detects the hotkey, and then blocks the hotkey from sending to all other applications. Of course, single keys like 'f' and 'shift' shouldn't be blocked.
Is it possible?

On Windows, you can use the keyboard library with suppress=True:
import keyboard

def my_func():
    # do something

keyboard.add_hotkey('shift+f', my_func, suppress=True)


That does work! But unfortunately now I have a threading problem. I have a while true and some other keyboard actions insider my_func, and the program seems to not work.

Just wanted to point out that pynput also has a suppress feature, when you call the listener like this: with Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True):. It may solve your threading problem.
